# Mostrar código según tamaño de pantalla

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, responsive

Quiero que me muestre el código del `ins` y el `script` cuando se ve desde el celular/móvil y que me muestre la otra de `amp-ad` en los otros tamaños de pantalla.

He probado a hacerlo con los `media query` en `css` pero eso solo modifica el estilo y no el código que se imprime en la página. Llevo semanas buscando información pero no la encuentro. No sé de qué punto de partida puedo empezar ya.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6312653245448669"
     data-ad-slot="4349498964"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

---

```
<amp-ad
   layout="fixed"
   width=336
   height=280
   type="adsense"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-6312653245448669"
   data-ad-slot="4349498964">
</amp-ad>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te des una idea de cómo se puede lograr con `Bootstrap 4` te dejo este ejemplo:

> Ejecutar snnipet en pantalla completa

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Breakpoints</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="my-3">
        Nivel Actual / breakpoint:
        <span class="badge badge-primary d-inline d-sm-none">xs</span> 
        <span class="badge badge-secondary d-none d-sm-inline d-md-none">sm</span> 
        <span class="badge badge-success d-none d-md-inline d-lg-none">md</span> 
        <span class="badge badge-warning d-none d-lg-inline d-xl-none">lg</span> 
        <span class="badge badge-danger d-none d-xl-inline">xl</span> 
        (= visible solo en este breakpoint)
    </div>
    <hr>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Oculto en pantallas inferiores a xs <br></span>
    <span class="d-none d-md-block">Oculto en pantallas inferiores a sm <br></span>
    <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Oculto en pantallas inferiores a md <br></span>
    <span class="d-none d-xl-block">Oculto en pantallas inferiores a lg <br></span>
    <div class="w-100 my-2"> <hr> </div>
    <span class="d-none">Oculto en pantallas superiores a xs <br></span>
    <span class="d-sm-none">Oculto en pantallas superiores a sm <br></span>
    <span class="d-md-none">Oculto en pantallas superiores a md <br></span>
    <span class="d-lg-none">Oculto en pantallas superiores a lg <br></span>
    <span class="d-xl-none">Oculto en pantallas superiores a xl <br></span>
    <div class="w-100 my-2"> <hr> </div>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Oculto solo en pantallas xs</span>
    <span class="d-block d-sm-none d-md-block">Oculto solo en pantallas sm <br></span>
    <span class="d-block d-md-none d-lg-block">Oculto solo en pantallas md <br></span>
    <span class="d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block">Oculto solo en pantallas lg <br></span>
    <span class="d-block d-xl-none">Oculto solo en pantallas xl <br></span>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahora, en tu caso lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container d-md-none">
<h3>Dispositivos móviles</h3>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6312653245448669"
     data-ad-slot="4349498964">
  </ins>
  <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>
<div class="container d-none d-md-block">
<h3>Pantallas superiores</h3>
  <amp-ad
     layout="fixed"
     width=336
     height=280
     type="adsense"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6312653245448669"
     data-ad-slot="4349498964">
  </amp-ad>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Las últimas 3 `script` son necesarias?

Comment: Puedes probar, si deseas. Acabo de hacer una prueba en `jsfiddle` y funciona sin ellas. Pero ten en cuenta que son dependencias de `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Sí, parece que para lo que lo estamos utilizando sí que funciona sin problemas.